# how do i access son object nodes in scala view

Tags: java, json, scala, playframework

//this is part of my controller

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Result list() {
    List models = EmployeeService.paginate();
    Long count = EmployeeService.count();    
  ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    result.put("data",Json.toJson(models));
   result.put("total", count);
    return ok(result);
}
```

//this is my view index.scala.view

```
@(a: Object)
<html>
</head>
<body >
@a.data[0].id

</body>
</html>
```

this gives "data is not a member of object"

{"data":[{"id":9,"sms_limit":"10000","sms_counter":"0"}]}

how do i access id and sms-limit ?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: how do i access id and sms-limit ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact requirement but if you want to found the value for id and sms_limit you can use this

```
val json:Option[Any] = JSON.parseFull("{"data":[{"id":9,"sms_limit":"10000","sms_counter":"0"}]}")
val list:Map[String,Any] = json.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]
for((key,value)<-list)
{
key match 
{
case "data" => var t=value.asInstanceOf[List[String,Any]]
             for((x,k)<-t )
               {
                  x match 
                     {
                        case "id " => println(k)
                        case "sms_limit" => println(k)
                        case _ =>
                      }

                }
case _ =>

}
```

It is not a good approach but work if you know about your file that it may not change in future

Comment: won't this be in the controller file?
how will i pass all values of id and sms_limit to view file,because i want to display them in a table.

Comment: i would like to dol the coding in java.

Comment: @AmanKothari you can certainly store these value in a map or a List then pass this to your another file